# Using CSS only to position 3 elements equally around a circle

Tags: css, math, position

I am trying to position 3 elements around a circle using CSS only. I have nudged the elements into position by eye, but I am assuming there is a mathematical (**PLEASE NOTE:** mathematical, **NOT** programatic) way to determine the `top` and `left` numbers for each of the three elements.

The motive here is that I will be rotating the entire block, and the elements should be in the same position after each rotation.

```css
#rotator {
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

#rotator div {
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  border-radius: 12px;
  text-align: center;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);
}

#rotator div#a {
  top: -12px;
  left: 38px;
}

#rotator div#b {
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}

#rotator div#c {
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="rotator">
  <div id="a">a</div>
  <div id="b">b</div>
  <div id="c">c</div>
</div>
```

Comment: In a circle of radius `R`, the following three points form an equilateral triangle: `(0,R), (-R/2, R sqrt(3)/2), (-R/2, -R sqrt(3)/2)`. Explanation: 2pi/3 is a third of a full turn; cos(2pi/3) = -1/2; sin(2pi/3) = sqrt(3)/2. Similarly, 4pi/3 is two thirds of a full turn; cos(4pi/3) = (1/2); sin(4pi/3) = -sqrt(3)/2.

Comment: That makes sense - but is it possible to translate to simple `top` and `left` coordinates for each element?

Comment: I would try rounding it to the nearest integer.

Comment: whoever marked this as a duplicate - this is the question I created specifically because that post was created by me and was incorrectly marked as a duplicate. That is why this post goes over the top to emphasize that a CSS solution is required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you cannot do this without a preprocessor, for example SCSS. Thanks @Stef for the formula for the vertices of a regular triangle.

[CODE][1]
[1]: https://codepen.io/BlackStar1991/pen/xxVLMVG